# Dynamic creation of a graph meeting the conditions in Python and Networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, networkx

I have a list of nodes:

```
n = [a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4]
```

from which I want to create any graph, in which after choosing two any nodes and finding `nx.shortest_path` I will get all combinations of triples:

```
 comb = [[A, A, A], [A, A, B], [A, B, A], [A, B, B], [B, A, A], [B, A, B], [B, B, A], [B, B, B]]
```

Where `A` and`B` are the counterparts of nodes `a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4`.

For example, if the algorithm creates paths between nodes for me:

```
(a1, b1), (a2, a3), (a3, a4), (a3, b1), (b1, b2), (b2, b3)
```

then:

```
nx.shortest_path(g, a2, a4) == (a2, a3, a4), as a case representation (A, A, A)
nx.shortest_path(g, a2, b1) == (a2, a3, b1), as a case representation (A, A, B)
nx.shortest_path(g, a3, a1) == (a3, b1, a1), as a case representation (A, B, A)

and so on all combinations with 'comb'.
```

How would you take it from the algorithmic side?

Comment: I have difficulties understanding the task. Can you elaborate in more detail?

Comment: That is, having only a list of nodes, create any graph in which you can get representations of threes with 'comb' using the shortest path. Of course, depending on the number of nodes, you can build many graphs that meet such a condition, but I am interested in finding even one. Because in my case there are more nodes.

Comment: and the problem is that by adding consecutive paths it is easy to disrupt the previously found shortest paths.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are (algorithmically) searching for a graph that meets certain conditions. Firstly, I'm unclear what you mean by "counterpart" - do you mean that {a1, a2, a3, a4} are all "A"?

Comment: Ah, ok I think I understand now. You want a graph that is two-coloured where the shortest paths between each vertex have all combinations of colors. Oh, and does it have to be triples? That is to say, do you care about longer paths?

Comment: exactly Gilleain :) for now I focus on triplets, but later as I have the basis of the algorithm, I will want to extend it to longer paths.

Comment: Right, so the best approach might to be to focus on the mathematics of it first. Is there proof that a graph with these properties always exists? Usually, if you have such a proof, that can give a guide to how to actually construct it - although not necessarily efficiently!

Comment: unfortunately, nowhere in the sources have I found such a theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas and partial solutions.

From your example it is seen that graph is undirected (not directed.) In that case, if we shortest path between vertices X and Y produces triplet (A, A, B), than shortest path between Y and X produces triplet (B, A, A).

Idea is to start from a string that contains all triplets as consecutive characters, no matter of direction. In case of triplets that is string AAABABBB. Now we can substitute A's and B's with different a's and b's. That produces graph:

```
a1 - a2 - a3 - b1 - a4 - b2 - b3 - b4
```

This graph satisfies conditions.

In case of triplets we had a luck that we had enough nodes to substitute initial string. If we do not have enough nodes, than it is possible to merge upper graph nodes to reduce number of needed nodes. Merging is done between two nodes of same type (A or B) so that it doesn't produce loop of length < 2 * size_of_substrings - 1. In case of triplets loop can have length 5 or more. In case of upper string (AAABABBB) there are no nodes of same type with distance >= 5. Constraint on a loop is to not produce new shortest paths between nodes.

Check case with substring of length 4. Than we have initial string AAAABBAABABBAABBBB. We can merge A or B on distance >= 7. E.g. lets merge first A with single A in middle. That produces graph:

```
/-------\
AAAABBAAB
|
BBAABBBB
```

Note initial string has to be symmetric by exchanging A<->B. With that same reduction of A can be done to reduce opposite B.

Comment: interesting. if I analyze the idea, I will write it. at the current stage I managed to implement multiprocessing, but without a different approach to the algorithm, there will always be too little.