# Speeding-up nested loops with using parallel calculations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, parallel-processing

I have the following code with steps inside the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

# I create all combinations of triples from the set of numbers 1,2, ..., 7
a1 = list(map(list, itertools.product([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], repeat=3)))
# Output:
# [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 4]...e.t.c.

# I'm deleting sub-lists with repeating values      
aa=[]
for i in range(len(a1)):
    if len(list(set(a1[i])))==3:
        x = a1[i]
        aa.append(x)        
# Output:
# [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 5]...e.t.c. 

# I create a list of value representation from the 'aa' list      
aa_representation=[]
for i in range(len(aa)):
    y =''.join(map(str, ['b' if x%2 else 'a' for x in aa[i]]))
    aa_representation.append(y)    
# Output:
# ['aba', 'abb', 'aba', 'abb',..., 'bab']

# I create lists from values from 'aa' matching to the representations from the 'aa_representation' list
aaa=[]
aab=[]
aba=[]
baa=[]
abb=[]
bba=[]
bab=[]
bbb=[]
for i in range(len(aa_representation)):
    if aa_representation[i]=='aaa':
        aaa.append(aa[i])
    if aa_representation[i]=='aab':
        aab.append(aa[i])
    if aa_representation[i]=='aba':
        aba.append(aa[i])
    if aa_representation[i]=='baa':
        baa.append(aa[i])
    if aa_representation[i]=='abb':
        abb.append(aa[i])
    if aa_representation[i]=='bba':
        bba.append(aa[i])
    if aa_representation[i]=='bab':
        bab.append(aa[i])
    if aa_representation[i]=='bbb':
        bbb.append(aa[i])

# I create a list with sub-lists containing after each one value of a given representation
combinations=[]
for q in range(len(aaa)):
    for w in range(len(aab)):
        for e in range(len(aba)):
                for r in range(len(abb)):
                    for t in range(len(bbb)):
                                x = [aaa[q],aab[w],aba[e],abb[r],bbb[t]]
                                if 'something that reduces the number of matching combinations':
                                    combinations.append(x)
```

How could I speed up the execution of the code? Because for now it is as crude as the construction of a flail :) I could use some parallel calculations here? Cython is out of the question for the time being, because I did not have any contact with him. I will be very grateful for any comments.

Comment: While there are things that could be done, it's hard to see why you'd want to materialize such an enormous object, first multiple times in memory and then on disc.  What problem are you actually trying to solve that you believe this is the solution to?  I strongly suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @DSM unfortunately, this is not a problem XY :) although writing to the disk a bit pulled, but it was associated with the idea of breaking into pieces and saving fragments in different files. although the question is partly about my earlier problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892625/dynamic-creation-of-a-graph-meeting-the-conditions-in-python-and-networkx

Comment: because I did not find any mathematical solution to my problem in the sources, I decided to go more rudely;)

Comment: I'm now even more convinced this is an XY problem, but if you want to construct a file of several GB and use several more GB of memory for some reason of your own, no one's going to stop you. :-)  Enjoy!

Comment: well, the door does not always have to be opened with your hands, you can also use the head in a more direct way:D

Comment: I could, instead of using the list of `combinations`, I could use the rest of my function and not write it to the disk, but in any case the loop will not accelerate.

Comment: I have changed the description of the problem a bit.

Comment: What is the actual **`[TIME]`**-domain and **`[SPACE]`**-domain cost of the flail-processing inside the call to the evaluation of the **`if ( <something that reduces> )`** condition **in `[ns]` and `[MB]` of RAM mapped allocations?**